# MySQL - Column specific time zone during insert

Tags: mysql, timezone

Let's say I have 2 TIMESTAMP fields/columns, `event` and `stamp`. For `event` field, when we insert, I want to set time zone so that event will use user specified time zone. However, I don't want `stamp` to use that time zone. I want `stamp` to use whatever default time zone the server is using.

```
SET time_zone = <UTC offset>;
```

does not work since it will affect both `event` and `stamp` where we only want `event` to be affected by the time zone.

Is there a way to set time zone for specific columns during insert?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  Perhaps you don't need to do this at all.  Why not simply handle this in the web application layer?

Answer (score 1):

MySQL doesn't bother about timezones when you insert a date.

I would recommend storing the date/time in GMT (+00:00) and have another field that stores the timezone used (e.g. "Europe/Amsterdam").

**Edit**

I'm not entirely sure you would need the used timezone though, since you can format a GMT time in any way you'd like inside your scripts / apps.

Answer (score 0):

```
SET time_zone = <user timezone>;    
INSERT ... SET event = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), stamp = UTC_TIMESTAMP(), ...
```

or read more at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html